# Messenger bot using Botkit on AWS: "bodyParser is not defined" error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, botkit

I set up a Bitnami Node.JS instance on AWS. Installed default Botkit. Updated dependencies. Set up a basic Facebook page/app with Messenger integration. Attempted to run the default Messenger bot example (Facebook_bot.js).

Running the bot gets the following error on load:

```
ReferenceError: bodyParser is not defined
```

Since this is all out of the box and using the example Messenger bot, is this an issue with BotKit source? Or have I somehow managed to mess up the minimal setup involved here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can mean 1 of 3 things

- the node.js file *usually named index.js* does not have `var bodyParser = require('body-parser')` **less likely**
- you do not have body-parser installed from **npm** to do so in command line run `npm i body-parser --save`
- if this is a remote solution and AWS builds based off of package.json add the dependency

`"dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.17.2"
      }`

Comment: It was the first one. Thanks!